# Arreglar esta regex para que tome el la oracion que sigue a la ultima ocurrencia de una palabra diferente de you antes de unos 2 puntos

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, match

Necesitaria que solamente en los casos en donde la ultima oracion NO empiece con "you:" tomando todo lo que sigue al nombre del otro usuario seguido de los 2 puntos y lo almacene en la variable text.
El problema que tiene mi regex es que solo funciona para el caso hipotetico de que la persona se llame stranger pero tendria que funcionar para todas las personas sin importar su nombre, excepto si antes de los 2 puntos la persona se llama you: porque ahi no tendria que validar la regex

```py
import re

#No responder
input_text = """Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
"""

#Si responder porque el ultimo que escribio fue la otra persona
input_text = """Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
stranger:Ohh vaya eso suena genial
"""
regex = re.compile(r'Stranger:\s{,}')

if regex.match(input_text):
    separacion = regex.split(input_text)
    texto = " ".join(separacion[1:])
    print(text)

else:
    pass
```

Por ejemplo, en el primer input_text donde "you:" envio el ultimo mensaje, entonces no deberia hacer nada(osea no deberia validar la regex).
Pero en el segundo input_text donde fue alguien diferente de "you:", la variable `text` valdria "Ohh vaya eso suena genial"

Aqui hago una pequeña  update de la pregunta y muestro el code del OCR junto a su output utilizando `print(repr(text))`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso esta haciendo scraping de su propio codigo, pero sirve para probar que estan los caracteres de escape de salto de linea `\n`

```
' \n\n   \n\na ern\n\n/tesseract..tesseract_cnd\n\n \n\npanta:\n\n   \n \n\nHidth\n| 168, ‘top’: 168, ‘width\': 720,\n\n \n\nsct:\n\n \n\nShot - sct.grab(mon)\n\nImage. frombytes("RGB", (screenShot.width, screenShot.height), screenShot.rgb, )\n\n \n\np.array (img)\ncv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)\n\n \n\n   \n\n-("Te ;\n(repr(text))\n\nashow("window_name’, frame)\n\n2 -waitKey(33) & @xFF in (ord("q"), 27, ):\nveak\n\n \n\x0c'
```

Comment: tienen que ser regex? no sería mucho más simple partir el txt por `\n` para separar en líneas, ir a la última y si no empieza por you (`.startswith()`) entonces hacer split por los dos puntos?

Comment: Estoy usando un Reconosedor Optico de Caracteres para scraping de esos chats, y el OCR Tesseract te devuelve las cadenas sin los saltos indicados en `\n` , por eso no los habia puesto

Comment: Pero pusiste la cadena entre triple comillas y con saltos de línea en su interior. ¿Cómo te lo devuelve entonces el ocr? Todas las líneas pegadas? Por ejemplo ¿no hay nada entre la palabra "trabajo" y la palabra "stranger" de tu segundo ejemplo?

Comment: El OCR devuelve sin `\n`, si tu escribes eso en un txt lo guardara sin ningun simbolo, en consola tampoco aparece nada, tan solo copie y pegue un pequeño output de ejemplo, y le puse la tripe comilla para simular como son las entradas reales del OCR Tesseract

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir lo que se muestra cuando haces un `print(repr(ocr_output))`? Es importante tener perfectamente claro cómo es el texto de entrada para poder dar cualquier solución.

Comment: Ahi la actualizo añadiendo un screencapture del codigo que hice para tener una vision del escritorio y ver la salida que hace el OCR del propio code usando el `print(repr())`, con el cual si se ven las `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está es la expresión que buscas:

```
(?<!you):(.*)$
```

La forma general

```
(?<!xyz)abc
```

significa: *Reconocer 'abc' sólo cuando no es precedido de `xyz`.

Lo que quiero reconocer es un ":" precedido de algo que no es "you". Además, está tiene que ser la última ocurrencia dentro de un texto, por lo que agrego un "$", produciendo el patrón final:

```
(?<!you):(.*)$
```

La componente "(.*)" simplemente captura todo lo que viene después del ":", por si es de interes.

#### Demo

Uso `re.search` en lugar de `re.match` para buscar un calce en todo el texto, no sólo al comienzo.

La función `revisar` aplica el patrón a un texto y devuelve la última línea si cumple la condición, o `None` en caso contrario:

```
import re

#No responder
input_text1 = """Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
"""

#Si responder porque el ultimo que escribio fue la otra persona
input_text2 = """Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
stranger:Ohh vaya eso suena genial
"""
regex = re.compile('(?<!you):(.*)$')

def revisar(texto):
    salida = None
    m = regex.search(texto)
    if m:
        salida = m[1]
    return salida

print(input_text1, revisar(input_text1))
print()
print(input_text2, revisar(input_text2))
```

produce:

```
Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
 None

Stranger: Hola
you: Hola!
stranger:¿que comiste ayer por la mañana?
you:He ido a un restaurante de comida rapida cerca del trabajo
stranger:Ohh vaya eso suena genial
 Ohh vaya eso suena genial

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nota

Existen cuatro alternativas para reconocer textos en relación a otros:

```
d(?=r)      Reconoce d seguido por r.

(?<=r)d     Reconoce d precedido por r.

d(?!r)      Reconoce d si después no viene r.

(?<!r)d     Reconoce d si antes no viene r.
```

El único detalle es que "r" no es capturado, por lo que no sabras que valor tenía el texto.

Comment: Muchimas gracias por el detalle de la explicación encerio me ayuda un monton, lo unico que te iba a preguntar es acerca de como quitar esos : separadores que quedaron en la frase final.

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez. Corregí el código. En lugar de `m[0]`, que retorna toda la parte reconocida (desde los ":" hasta el final), usare `m[1]`, que retorna el *primer grupo de captura*, o sea, sólo lo reconocido por la exp. reg. entre paréntesis.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me re ayudarte!

Answer (score 2):

A la vista de la última captura de pantalla que adjuntas (que aunque no se ve gran cosa es suficiente para saber que el OCR sí que entrega retornos de carro separando las líneas), y aunque ya tienes la solución por la que preguntabas utilizando regexp, voy a darte otra que no necesita expresiones regulares.

Aprovechando que la salida del OCR tiene retornos de carro la solución es tan simple como usar `.strip().split("\n")[-1]` para partir por ese retorno de carro y quedarse después con el último elemento resultante (-1), que corresponderá a la última línea de texto (el `.strip()` previo es para eliminar una posible línea vacía al final).

Si esa línea comienza por algo diferente de "you", entonces nos interesa. Basta usar de nuevo `split(":", 1)` sobre esa línea para dividir por los dos puntos. El 1 indica que si el carácter ":" apareciera más veces en la misma línea, sólo queremos dividir por el primero de ellos. Eso nos dejará entonces esa última línea separada en dos trozos: el primero, quien habla, el segudo, lo que dice.

Por tanto todo lo anterior se reduce a dos líneas de código:

```py
ultima_linea = input_text.strip().split("\n")[-1]
if not ultima_linea.lower().startswith("you"):
  quien, frase = ultima_linea.split(":", 1)
  print(frase)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion y la respuesta, encerio son unos genios ;)